# Software to convert pictures of lectures from a blackboard to text

Tags: windows, android, ocr, image-conversion

Most of my subjects allows taking a picture of our lecture from a blackboard, because of this I took advantage of it and take a picture of all the lectures that we have.

Yesterday my professor said that we can open all notes except notes from our phone. Because of this, I am not able to open any kind of notes that I have from a phone.

Question: Is there an application where I can convert a picture of our lecture to text so I can print it?

Printing the picture is possible but it can have a great impact on the ink of my printer.

Example of picture lecture:

**Sample panorama photo**
[image: Sample picture of a lecture]

**Actual Photo**
[image: Actual Photo of lecture]

**Edit:** I am taking a picture using android 6.0 lollipop (Android One phone) and I have a desktop PC windows 8 and 10.

**Bonus:** If my account permits, I am willing to give +50 points to anyone that can consider physics formula. There are lectures that I've got from physics or math subjects.

Comment: I would look into OCR software, it may; though, be difficult to do this with human handwriting

Comment: Yes, that's my concern also.

Comment: Hmm, I'll add an answer now but [this](http://ocrsdk.com/documentation/quick-start/text-fields/) looks promising

Comment: Alright, I won't add an answer, it seems that it can only read separated individual characters and looking at the picture, I think it may have a hard time with that.

Comment: ok, one more recommendation I'll try, please tell me if this works out, [Infty Reader](http://www.inftyreader.org), it seems capable of both handwritten notes and [mathematical formulas](http://mathoverflow.net/a/95619/85740)

Comment: Ok, thanks! I'll try it later after working time. :)

Comment: You don't really need OCR, right? How about an app that would cut each column as an image, put each image on a page, and print the result?

Comment: Seems good, but how about the color? Does inverting the color works on all kinds of lecture? A photo of powerpoint presentation, blackboard, whiteboard, etc.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question and add which OSes are in the play? Eg what is running on the device where the pictures are on currently, and what do you have available on your computer alternatively?

Answer (score -2):

Nice Inftyreader software.
Personally I would just Photoshop and invert the pics or Color Range Select "White" then cut and paste on a black background then invert.  Like these I did to your pics.

[image: Invert 1]

Comment: This does not convert the image to text

Comment: one of my problems is wasting printer ink, it seems that this answer a little side of my question. But yeah, you are not converting it to text

Comment: Discable, please link to the software, see its price, and describe the steps to make it do what the asker wants. Also, please clearly seperate from the Photoshop answer.

Comment: Could we have some more information please?